# Disable metadata publishing for Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, wsdl, metadata, azure-cloud-services

How to disable Metadata publishing for an Azure Cloud Service?

I have looked in the .csdef file but there is no Configuration Element/Attribute for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still in the Web.config, that's how we do it as well.
The way to do it in the web.config, for reference, is:
In the `system.web` section, add

```
  <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <remove name="Documentation"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to add a web.config file in the service role and use:

```
<system.serviceModel>
```

like a standard wcf configuration file.